# Change Set Operations Not Working in AWS Ruby SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk-ruby

I cannot use any of the change set operations in the AWS Ruby SDK.  All other create/list/update/delete operations appear to work correctly, but any change set operation gives an error like `NoMethodError: undefined method 'list_change_sets' for #<Aws::CloudFormation::Client>`

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, the method is there: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/apis/cloudformation/2010-05-15/api-2.json#L233. I would pull the latest version from Github and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The Change Sets feature was added in [v2.2.31](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2231-2016-03-29) of the AWS Ruby SDK, so you will need to make sure that your current version is greater than or equal to this (using `Aws::VERSION`, or checking your `Gemfile.lock` if using Bundler).

If using Bundler, you can run `bundle update aws-sdk` to update the SDK to the latest version (make sure that the constraint in your `Gemfile` is appropriate), or if you're just using RubyGems directly run `gem update aws-sdk`.